# How to create notification hub tags programmatically?

Tags: azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am new to Azure Notification Hub. I am implementing Azure Notification Hub for sending push notifications to mobile apps developed using Cordova.

Can anyone show me some sample code to create TAGS from ASP.Net Azure SDK?

Comment: Did you check the *Azure* SDK?

Comment: Yes, I didn't get any helpful info.

Comment: Your question mentioned *ASP.NET* instead of Azure. I suggest you check the proper pages, try googling what you asked here "Azure Notification Tags API". Or search SO - there are a lot of relevant questions.

Comment: You might find this blog useful: http://blog.repsaj.nl/index.php/2016/08/azure-custom-function-bindings-notification-tags-in-cordova-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to the tag from your app, it saves in backend as a part of the Registration entity. Then you just send the notification to that tag. You can see the registrations in the backend using Visual Studio or Service Bus Explorer.